# Angular Material & Flex: How set max width for whole app?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I want to set the width of the app content so that when screen sizes changes, the content stays in the middle and there are whitespace on left and right side. I am using Angular Material & Angular Flex. I have observed this is a common design in various websites including stack overflow. Pardon me if this is a common question and I'm unable to find it.

Here is an example: 
I want the app content to be within the lines. 
[image]

Comment: There are many ways to do it. I'd suggest you use the developer tools in your browser to see how they've done it, or use a css framework such as bootstrap

Comment: I am using Angular Material

Comment: app root set max-width and `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [max-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width') for the style of your app-root

Sample:

```
.entire-app {
    max-width: 750px;

    /* Centers the class */
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set the max-width for the app easily, you can do it in the style.css of your angular application like this

```
body {

  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

what it will do is set the max-width for your app and will make the content in the center, you can also use flexbox to make the content center but its fine if you do it by margin below is the link for stackblitz. remember i have given border so that you can see the content is in the middle please remove it when you are done with test.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p9g262?file=src%2Fstyles.css

Answer (score -1):

Best way to do it is using flex. It will define how much a flexbox item should grow or not. 
A example of the usage is as the following:

```
fxFlex="grow shrink initial"
fxFlex="0 1 80" <- Will not grow | will shrink 1:1 | initial value of 80%
fxFlex="0 1 1250px" <- Will not grow | will shrink to 1:1 | initial value of 1250px
```

For more please read this [documentation](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxFlex-API)